# Average Case Big O and the Impact of Sorting

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, big-o

I'm looking at the time complexity for implementations of a method which determines if a `String` contains all unique characters.

The basic, *brute force*, approach would be to iterate through the `String` one character at a time maintaining a `HashSet` of *seen* characters. For each character in the iteration we check if the `Set` already contains it, and if so return `false`. We return `true` if the entire `String` has been searched. This would be `O(n)` as a worst case complexity. What would be the average case? `O(n/2)`?

If we try to optimise this by sorting the `String` into a `char` array, would it be more or less efficient? Sorting typically takes `O(n log n)` which is worse than `O(n)`, but a sorted `String` allows for duplicate characters to be detected much earlier (especially for long strings).

Do we say the worst case is `O(n^2 log n)` but the average case is better? If so, what is it?

Comment: As a simple comment, there's no such thing as `O(n/2)`, it is always "rounded" to remove constants.

Comment: The answer depends on what you call a "character". If you have say 256 characters, then for any strings of length 257 and up the answer would be yes, so you only ever need to check no more than 256 elements, hence the complexity is O(1). If the size of your character set is "very large" (much larger than the size of the input) then characters essentially never repeat, so you will find a duplicate and bail out with probability of about zero.

Comment: @n.m. You are half wrong on that. Strictly talking, this comparison time cost is O(n) as it depends on string length. It is true that for a small dataset, it can be reduced to constant time, but it cannot be counted as the real notation.

Comment: @Shirkam it depends on the string lengtgh only if the size of the character set is larger than the string length. Otherwise it is bounded from above by the size of the character set. If that size is constant, then so is the size of the entire problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the un-sorted case, the average case depends entirely on the string! Without knowing/assuming any distribution, it's hard to make any assumption.

A simple case, for a string with randomly-placed characters, where one of the characters repeats once:

- the number of possibilities for the repeated characters being arranged is `n*(n-1)/2`
- the probability it is detected repeated in exactly `k` steps is `(k-1)/(n-1)`
- the probability it is detected in at most `k` steps is `(k*(k-1))/(n*(n-1))`, meaning that on average you will detect it (for large `n`) in about `0.7071*n`... [incomplete]

For multiple characters that occur with different frequencies, or you make different assumptions on how characters are distributed in the string, you'll get different probabilities.

Hopefully someone can extend on my answer! :)

---

If the string is sorted, then you don't need the HashSet.

However, the average case still depends on the distribution of characters in the string: if you get two `aa` in the beggining, it's pretty efficient; if you get two `zz`, then you didn't win anything.

The worst case is sorting **plus** detecting-duplicates, so `O(n log n + n)`, or just `O(n log n)`.

So, it appears it's not advantageous to sort the string beforehand, due to the increased complexity, both in average-case and worst-case.

Comment: So, your answer is, time complexity with a random generated string is `O(n)`, isn't it?

Comment: Worst case with a random string is `O(n)`, yes

Comment: The probability of detecting a duplicate in k steps is not (k-1)/(n-1). For example k=2, the probability is 2/(n(n-1)), and k=n, the probability is 2/n. (And as n.m. comments on the question, this assumes an infinite number of characters).